# NUnit-Selenium exception is not considered Failed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit

I use this code to validate Failure in NUnit at end of test execution-

```
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
{
   do something
}
```

The issue I have is the Selenium NoSuchElement exception is not considered a Failure, hence when it reaches above code. The status is still PASSED. The way I handled it was adding Assert.Fail() in catch section of Selenium code to force the NUnit to fail. Is this right way of doing it or there is other ways? I am triggering NuNit tests from batch file

Answer (score 0):

Are you swallowing the NoSuchElement exception somewhere? As it should result in a failed test.

Comment: My bad,the status was not getting updated properly as was confused on annotations [Test],[TestFixtureTearDown],[TearDown]. So , basically any Error or exceptions is captured as "FAILED" in NUnit.NoSuchElement, UnHandledAlertOpen, NoSuchFrame.Thanks.